# Add product ratings to an Array of objects JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an Array of Objects containing different product names. Each object also contains a rating (1 star, 2 stars, 3 stars, 4 stars, 5 stars).

```
let myProducts = [
    {
        productName: "Name of the product",
        rating: '5 Stars',
    },
    {
        productName: "Name of the product",
        rating: '4 Stars',
    },
    {
        productName: "Name of the product",
        rating: '3 Stars',
    },
    {
        productName: "Name of the product",
        rating: '5 Stars',
    },
    {
        productName: "Name of the product",
        rating: '4 Stars',
    },
]
```

As well as the number of stars shown, I also want to include individual ratings. The user should be able to see each individual rating, the user who wrote that rating and the text included in that rating.

Comment: Please clarify. Are you asking about a data structure to hold individual ratings, or a complete web page? Without any explanation of what you have tried so far, this sounds like you want us to design and build a complete web page for you. That is out of scope for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an array to each item with the individual ratings. This architecture can help you:

```
let myProducts = [
    {
        productName: "Name of the product",
        rating: '5 Stars',
        individualRatings: [
            {
                rating: 5,
                user: "John Doe",
                text: "I really enjoyed this product!"
            },
            {
                rating: 4,
                user: "Jane Doe",
                text: "It was ok."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        productName: "Name of the product",
        rating: '4 Stars',
        individualRatings: [
            {
                rating: 4,
                user: "John Doe",
                text: "I really enjoyed this product!"
            },
            {
                rating: 3,
                user: "Jane Doe",
                text: "It was ok."
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Extra: Then you can also generate an average between all the IndividualRatings to get the final rating of the product. Also you can delete the general rating and calculate this in the client side maping rating in IndividualRatings (ex: `IndividualRatings[x].rating`)